# How to style the Drawer - Expo navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, expo

I am new to react native. I was trying to add a drawer navigator, and by default it's blue, is there a way to change this color? I am using the native base Library, Here is a screenshot and snippets of my codes to clarify what I'm asking. Thanks[image]
Drawer component in my app.js is structured like this:

```js
const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1, marginTop:12 }}>
    <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'center' }}>
      <Image source={require('./assets/icon.png')} style={{height:120,width:120,borderRadius:60}}/>
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props}/>
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Here is one of the screens too:

```js
class LibraryScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon : ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name="home" style={{fontSize:24, color:tintColor}}/>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left style={{justifyContent:"flex-start",flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
            <Icon name="menu" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
          </Left>
        </Header>
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Text>Library Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LibraryScreen;
```

Comment: it's always helpful to share some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Edited it, check it out if it helps in any way

Comment: I guess the solution below didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style to the `<Header>` component

```
<Header
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}>
```

Full code

```
class LibraryScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
  drawerIcon : ({tintColor}) => (
    <Icon name="home" style={{fontSize:24, color:tintColor}}/>
  )
 } 
 render() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Header
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Left style={{justifyContent:"flex-start",flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
          <Icon name="menu" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
        </Left>
      </Header>
      <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Text>Library Screen</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

export default LibraryScreen;

Comment: Thank you for saving my day